# Append style or js script to layout in phoenix template

Tags: javascript, css, templates, elixir, phoenix-framework

Using Phoenix templates, I'd like to append css and js script to the current page layout head.

Looking in phoenix documentation, I didn't found anything about this.

This would help me requiring minimal amount of css and js for each of my pages, instead of one massive css and one js file.

Comment: https://blog.diacode.com/page-specific-javascript-in-phoenix-framework-pt-1

Comment: The way described here depend mainly on JS. I assume there is something in phoenix to do this.

Comment: So you want `<script src="page-specific.js"></script>` to be added to various pages where you pass `"page-specific.js"` from a controller action? Are you using brunch?

Answer (score 0):

Every Phoenix project has own layout files- `/web/views/layout_view.ex` to handle it as view and layout template- `/web/templates/layout/app.html.eex`.

I'm not so sure, this is what you asked, but to append your `css` or `js` file in layout, just add following lines:

```
# CSS
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= static_path(@conn, "/css/<your_css>.css") %>">

# JS
<script src="<%= static_path(@conn, "/js/app.js") %>"></script>
```

where `static_path` by default points to `/web/static/`.

Also in your controllers you can change the layout with:

```
plug :put_layout, "MyLayout.html"
```